# How to retrive data for n array of objects in jquery templates?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-templates

```
var json = [{
    "id": "702",
    "nid": "1",
    "node_count": "211",
    "sdata": "100",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-04 09:00:42"
}][{
    "id": "697",
    "nid": "2",
    "node_count": "218",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-0    4 08:41:05"
}][{
    "id": "700",
    "nid": "3",
    "node_count": "217",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-04 08:41:52"
}][{
    "id": "699",
    "nid": "4",
    "node_count": "33",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-0    4-04 08:41:46"
}][{
    "id": "701",
    "nid": "5",
    "node_count": "23",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-04 08:42:20"
}]
$.each(json, function (arrayID, SensorData) {

    alert('Node id' + SensorData.nid);
    alert('SensorData' + SensorData.sdata);
    alert('Sensor  Type' + SensorData.stype);
    alert('Time is ' + SensorData.timestamp);

});
```

Comment: Your syntax is completely invalid. Also, some explanation of the issue and what you're trying to achieve would help *a lot*.

Comment: Rory could you please help me how retrieve data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json you are looking for should be something like this.

```
var json = [{
    "id": "702",
    "nid": "1",
    "node_count": "211",
    "sdata": "100",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-04 09:00:42"
   },
   {
    "id": "697",
    "nid": "2",
    "node_count": "218",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-0    4 08:41:05"
  },
  {
    "id": "700",
    "nid": "3",
    "node_count": "217",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-04 08:41:52"
  },
  {
    "id": "699",
    "nid": "4",
    "node_count": "33",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-0    4-04 08:41:46"
},{
    "id": "701",
    "nid": "5",
    "node_count": "23",
    "sdata": "0",
    "stype": "1",
    "timestamp": "2014-04-04 08:42:20"
}];
```

Comment: i am not getting this way

Comment: Refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/KEeyU/1/

Comment: I had already tested , that one ,but my json data is not came as you suggested

Comment: What exactly your looking for?

Comment: As the above question my data is came on that form , i want to use  that one ,to show each one in different table